# How to get Reply value of any discussion from discussion list using javascript

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, discussion-board

i am trying to get text value  from reply of any discussion using JavaScript. i am easily getting the reply count but don't require that. i want show top most reply on the basis of rating.

Not able to do .. please help

Comment: Did you used jquery to read the "reply html tag", it would be having some unique css class which we can read....can you put your html of page which is showing replies.....

Comment: hi Siddharth ,  i want get all items of discussion list with there best reply / first reply of that item. this should be done dynamically.